# How Change in CodeBehind HeaderImage in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How to dynamically change the image that is in the header?

The idea is to do it when the grid is created in the "ItemDataBound" event

This is my Grid

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgMain" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PId" Visible="false" />
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderImageUrl="ico_estadistica_despacho.png">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEst" runat="server" BorderWidth="0" ImageUrl="punto.png" CommandName="EstDesp"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="CotId" Visible="false" />
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I tried something, but did not work out.

```
 If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Header Then
        dgMain2.Columns.Item(1).HeaderImageUrl = "/Images/ico_estadistica_despacho_redi.png"
  End If
```

Comment: You only have 3 columns in your DataGrid but you are trying to change the `HeaderImageUrl` of the 9th column.

Comment: Oh, sorry, delete the other columns to the grid does not occupy much space in question.I fix it right away.

Comment: No problem. Remember that the DataGridColumnCollection is 0-indexed. So column one would start at index 0. If you are wanting to change the second column, you would use index 1.

Comment: So by your last edit, I take it to mean even with the correct index, the header image still isn't changing? Are you 100% sure that your path to the image is correct?